# Remove gutter from card columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

How do you remove the gutters between the columns and rows in Bootstrap 4's `.card-columns` container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.card-columns` container makes use of [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) and defines a [column-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap).

To remove the gutter between the columns, you'll need to remove the column gap:

```
.no-gutter-card-deck.card-columns {
  column-gap: 0;
}
```

To remove the gutter between the rows, you'll need to remove the margins around the cards:

```
.no-gutter-card > .card {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/vLfsAlZFRn